# How can I power off a VM on vCenter using Pulumi

Tags: vsphere, pulumi, vcenter

We are trying to create a remote desktop service that allows users to manage and access remote desktops where each remote desktop is a virtual machine on a vCenter. Users should be able to create and destroy them often. I am evaluating Pulumi as a possible way for us to manage those virtual machines but I don't understand how to use it to power off an existing VM.

I Tried creating a VM using [`vsphere.VirtualMachine`](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/vsphere/api-docs/virtualmachine/?utm_source=performance-max&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=&utm_term=&utm_medium=ppc&utm_source=adwords&hsa_grp=&hsa_cam=18353585506&hsa_mt=&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&hsa_acc=1926559913&hsa_ad=&hsa_src=x&hsa_tgt=&hsa_kw=&gclid=Cj0KCQiA1ZGcBhCoARIsAGQ0kkrqMfxbmWp_tgV_6D4BOSU58ulEjackCeeEH3GQu7sTmiNTBXyBWtwaAr9OEALw_wcB#virtualmachine) and expected there to be a `powerState` parameter that allows me to control whether the vm should be on or off, but I cant find such parameter. It seems that the only input parameters concerned with power state are [forcePowerOff](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/vsphere/api-docs/virtualmachine/?utm_source=performance-max&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=&utm_term=&utm_medium=ppc&utm_source=adwords&hsa_grp=&hsa_cam=18353585506&hsa_mt=&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&hsa_acc=1926559913&hsa_ad=&hsa_src=x&hsa_tgt=&hsa_kw=&gclid=Cj0KCQiA1ZGcBhCoARIsAGQ0kkrqMfxbmWp_tgV_6D4BOSU58ulEjackCeeEH3GQu7sTmiNTBXyBWtwaAr9OEALw_wcB#forcepoweroff_nodejs), [poweronTimeout](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/vsphere/api-docs/virtualmachine/?utm_source=performance-max&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=&utm_term=&utm_medium=ppc&utm_source=adwords&hsa_grp=&hsa_cam=18353585506&hsa_mt=&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&hsa_acc=1926559913&hsa_ad=&hsa_src=x&hsa_tgt=&hsa_kw=&gclid=Cj0KCQiA1ZGcBhCoARIsAGQ0kkrqMfxbmWp_tgV_6D4BOSU58ulEjackCeeEH3GQu7sTmiNTBXyBWtwaAr9OEALw_wcB#powerontimeout_nodejs), and [shutdownWaitTimeout](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/vsphere/api-docs/virtualmachine/?utm_source=performance-max&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=&utm_term=&utm_medium=ppc&utm_source=adwords&hsa_grp=&hsa_cam=18353585506&hsa_mt=&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&hsa_acc=1926559913&hsa_ad=&hsa_src=x&hsa_tgt=&hsa_kw=&gclid=Cj0KCQiA1ZGcBhCoARIsAGQ0kkrqMfxbmWp_tgV_6D4BOSU58ulEjackCeeEH3GQu7sTmiNTBXyBWtwaAr9OEALw_wcB#shutdownwaittimeout_nodejs). There is however a [powerState](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/vsphere/api-docs/virtualmachine/?utm_source=performance-max&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=&utm_term=&utm_medium=ppc&utm_source=adwords&hsa_grp=&hsa_cam=18353585506&hsa_mt=&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&hsa_acc=1926559913&hsa_ad=&hsa_src=x&hsa_tgt=&hsa_kw=&gclid=Cj0KCQiA1ZGcBhCoARIsAGQ0kkrqMfxbmWp_tgV_6D4BOSU58ulEjackCeeEH3GQu7sTmiNTBXyBWtwaAr9OEALw_wcB#powerstate_nodejs) output.

Answer (score 0):

Pulumi is an infrastructure deployment tool. It uses the providers' APIs to create and configure resources: it is concerned only with "deploy-time" problems.

Turning a machine on or off is a "run-time" problem. Pulumi isn't designed to handle this sort of issue. Things like running a program on the machine, or listing the directory contents of a bucket, are just not what Pulumi is for. Consider the risk this sort of thing brings: your code is run to create a new environment; and later, to eliminate drift and ensure the resources are configured correctly. If every time you checked your infrastructure for drift (`pulumi up`) you also turned off a machine (even if it's in use), then you'd have some angry users, I think?

vSphere's own APIs may provide a way to do this from your program. The Pulumi provider doesn't.